# how to scroll down to the bottom for items inside div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>   
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    window.scroll(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hahaha">
        <% for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {%>
            <div><%=i%></div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
        <% for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {%>
        <div><%=i%></div>
    <% } %>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#hahaha{
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

this code only works on the main scroll bar which located on the right side of browser, but doesn't work inside the div tag, can anyone show me how to make the content which located inside the div to scroll to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can do it this way:

```
var bottom= $('div').height()+$('div').prop('scrollHeight');    
$('div').scrollTop(bottom);
```

or if you wanna animate it:

```
var bottom= $('div').height()+$('div').prop('scrollHeight');    
$('div').animate({scrollTop:bottom},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the example you can use [**Offset**](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [**Position**](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to find the position of the div to which you want to scroll

using `offset`

[**JS fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/8a127ws1/)

usign `position`

[**JS fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/8a127ws1/1/)

```
$(window).load(function () {
     var pos = $('.scrollhere').position()  // or .offset
     var toppos = pos.top
     $('#scrolling').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': toppos
     }, 1000)
 })
```